# R: Mutate last sequence of specific values

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I have a dataframe containing columns with 0's and 1's. I want to mutate the last sequence of 1's into zeros like this:

```
# data
  
a <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1)
b <- c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1)

c <- data.frame(cbind(a,b))
head(c,7)

# desired output

a_desired <- c(0,1,1,0,0,0,0)
b_desired <- c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0)

c_desired <- data.frame(cbind(a_desired,b_desired))
head(c_desired,7)
```

such that I end up with the same sequence except that the last sequence of 1's has been mutated into 0's. I've tried using tail() but haven't found a solution so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try using `rle`

```
apply(c, 2, function(x){
  y <- max(which(rle(x == 1)$values))
  x[(sum(rle(x == 1)$lengths[1:(y-1)]) + 1): sum(rle(x == 1)$lengths[1:y])] <- 0
  x
})

     a b
[1,] 0 0
[2,] 1 1
[3,] 1 1
[4,] 0 1
[5,] 0 0
[6,] 0 0
[7,] 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`purrr::map` variant

```
library(purrr)

map(c, function(x){
  
  last1 <- max(which(x == 1))
  last0 <- which(x[1:last1] == 0)
  
  c(x[seq_len(max(last0))], rep(0, length(x) - max(last0))) 

})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a combination of `cumsum` of `x == 0` and replace the values where this is equal to `max`.

```
sapply(c, function(x) {
  . <- cumsum(diff(c(0,x)==1)==1)
  `[<-`(x, . == max(.), 0L)
  #replace(x, . == max(.), 0L) #Alternaive to [<-
})
#     a b
#[1,] 0 0
#[2,] 1 1
#[3,] 1 1
#[4,] 0 1
#[5,] 0 0
#[6,] 0 0
#[7,] 0 0
```

Or the same but written i a different way (thanks to @thelatemail
)

```
sapply(c, function(x) {
  cs <- cumsum(diff(c(0,x)==1)==1)
  x[cs == max(cs)] <- 0L
  x
})
```

Or another variant iterating from the last element to the beginning until 0 is found.

```
sapply(c, function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  i <- n
  while(x[i] != 1 & i>1L) i <- i-1L
  while(x[i] != 0 & i>1L) i <- i-1L
  x[i:n] <- 0L
  x  
})
```

Comment: I like the logic, but that is difficult to parse mentally with the `.` and directly calling of the replacement function. Why not `cs <- cumsum(x == 0); x[cs == max(cs)] <- 0; x` or something similar?

Comment: I wish I could use `cumsum(x == 0) |> replace(x, _ == max(_), 0)` but base pipes allow to use the placeholder only at one position. With magritr it would be `cumsum(x == 0) %>% replace(x, . == max(.), 0)`. But loading a package only for that? So I end up storing it at `.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own function:

```
fun <- function(x){
  y <- rle(x)
  y$values[length(y$values)] <- 0
  inverse.rle(y)
}
```

Now run:

```
data.frame(sapply(c, fun))
  a b
1 0 0
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 0 1
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0
```

Comment: This does assume `1`s are always the final run at the end of the vector, which might not be the case (granted, it works for the example shown in the question).

Comment: @thelatemail the question clearly states that the columns only contain 0's and 1's. Now whatever happen at the final run of the vector, replacing 0 with 0 has no impact, but replacing 1 with 0 has the effect required. So just replace the last value with 0. Either the 1 is replaced with 0 or the 0 is maintained

Comment: Good point. I missed that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you sequences always end with `1`s, you can try (given `df <- data.frame(a,b)`)

```
> df * sapply(df, function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x != 1)) != 0))
  a b
1 0 0
2 1 1
3 1 1
4 0 1
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0
```